# Plotting a line at open levels until they are hit

Tags: pine-script

I want a script that plots a line at the levels flatbottom or flat top until they are breached, at which point I want the line to delete itself.  Getting a bit stuck here...

The two plotshapes show examples where the purple line should delete itself..

I think I need to use xloc bar index somehow but Im not sure how

```
//@version=4
study("Flat Bottom",overlay=true)
timeframe=timeframe.multiplier>=240?true:false
flatbottom= low == open and (timeframe or timeframe.isdwm)
flattop = high == open and (timeframe or timeframe.isdwm)



currentYear = year(timenow)
currentMonth = month(timenow)
currentDay = dayofmonth(timenow)
today = year == currentYear and month == currentMonth and dayofmonth == currentDay

plotshape(barssince(flatbottom)==1 and low<open[1]) 
plotshape(barssince(flattop)==1 and high>open[1]) 

var lineLevel = float(na)
if (flatbottom or flattop)
    lineLevel := open
    line line_3 = line.new(time, open, time + 60 * 60 * 24,open, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.purple, width=1)
```

---

Tying to figure out for loops for breachBot and breachTop

```
// ————— Label-creating condition
var flatb = false
flatb := flatbottom

var flatt = false
flatt := flattop

// ————— Count number of bars since last 
var barCountfb = 0
barCountfb := flatb ? not flatb[1] ? 1 : barCountfb + 1 : 0

var barCountft = 0
barCountft := flatt ? not flatt[1] ? 1 : barCountft + 1 : 0

// ————— Create labels while keeping a trail of label ids in series "lbl".
// This is how we will later identify the bars where a label exist.
label lbltop = na
if flatt
    lbltop := label.new(bar_index, high, tostring(barCountft), xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, size = size.small,textcolor=color.white,color=color.purple)

label lblbot = na
if flatb
    lblbot := label.new(bar_index, low, tostring(barCountfb), xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, size = size.small,textcolor=color.white,color=color.purple,style=label.style_label_up)



var breachBot = false
for i = 1 to 4000
    if not na(lblbot[i])
        // We have identified a bar where a label was created.
        if barssince(flatbottom)==i and low<open[i]
            breachBot == true


var breachTop = false
for i = 1 to 4000
    if not na(lbltop[i])
        // We have identified a bar where a label was created.
       if barssince(flattop)==i and high>open[i]
            label.delete(lbltop[i])
            breachTop = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we keep track of bottom and top lines separately, and remember the line id when they are created so we can delete them if needed. This will only delete lines where your `X` plotted:

```
//@version=4
study("Flat Bottom",overlay=true)
timeframe=timeframe.multiplier>=240?true:false
flatbottom= low == open and (timeframe or timeframe.isdwm)
flattop = high == open and (timeframe or timeframe.isdwm)

currentYear = year(timenow)
currentMonth = month(timenow)
currentDay = dayofmonth(timenow)
today = year == currentYear and month == currentMonth and dayofmonth == currentDay

var line lineTop = na
var line lineBot = na
breachBot = barssince(flatbottom)==1 and low<open[1]
breachTop = barssince(flattop)==1 and high>open[1]

// Delete lines on breach.
if breachBot
    line.delete(lineBot)
if breachTop
    line.delete(lineTop)
// Create lines on new flat top/bot.
if flatbottom
    lineBot := line.new(time, open, time + 60 * 60 * 24,open, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.purple, width=1)
if flattop
    lineTop := line.new(time, open, time + 60 * 60 * 24,open, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.green, width=1)

plotshape(breachBot) 
plotshape(breachTop)
```

Comment: awesome and then i just need to find a shorthand way of doing this but for every bar back in time... barssince(flatbottom)==1 and low<open[1] or barssince(flatbottom)==2 and low<open[2] or etc...

Comment: could you help with the for loop to iterate all bars back available for breachBot and breachTop?

Comment: You could use a technique similar to the one found [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-keep-only-the-last-x-labels-or-lines), but with the current state of affairs in handling past drawings ids, I don't recommend `for` loop sweeps of the past trying to clean everything, as our scripts will frequently run into limitations that make it impractical to achieve this reliably. Best to keep your lookback on the short side.

Comment: I have this code but it always returns false and not sure why... 'code' var breachBot = false for i = 1 to maxBarsBack if barssince(flatbottom)==i and low<open[i] breachBot = true 'code'

Comment: Don't recommend using `barssince()` in a for loop.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dK25iaKC this seems like a better way to do it...but line.delete is not working